# How to set onclicklistener listview to send to another listview

Tags: java, android

```
    String [] item= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Liste);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row_item,R.id.textView,item);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int p, long id) {



        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you update this question with more details?

Comment: Define Your problem statement clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Just onClick with ListView to another ListView with onClick. Then onClick to the ListView. Thanks sir.